# My application breaks down when I reload the concrete page using react routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes, react-router

I have a news web-application and I`m trying to create a publication page, my situation is next, I have a list of publications, then I click on one of them and visit a page with all the information about the publication I clicked on, when I visit this page for the first time, everything is ok, but when I reload it my application breaks down and I see a meaningless error in the console, because after the page is reloaded, instead of loading the page it is trying to load some css file, I dont know how to explain. but when I visit this page for the first time my `Sources` look like this.

[image]

But when I reload the page it looks like this.

[image]

As I said I dont know how to explain everything right, so I'll just provide everything I can.

The error I have:

[image]

And my url:

`http://localhost:8080/publications/by-id/publication-eight`

I hope you guys help me with this.

Comment: Click on `http://localhost:8080/publications/by-id/publication-eight/styles.css` and check if you see the actual css file or not. Probably you'll see a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I've found the solution. My app didn't work when the url has more than one segment after the root `/`. So the solution is to add `<base href="/">` to the `head` section of the `index.html` file, but my other apps worked and still work without it, I checked 2 of the apps I created and I have no idea why they work without `<base href="/">`.